# Typing British pound sign Ubuntu 13.10 - Spanish keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, layout

I would like to know how to type the British pound sign in Ubuntu 13.10.  I am new to Ubuntu and using a Spanish keyboard layout.  The keyboard layout shows it as in the top right quadrant of the 3 key but i don't know how to get it.

Comment: May you add some screenshots, please?

Answer (score 3):

Go into Settings then Keyboard. On the typing tab click "Layout Settings" at the bottom. Now on the layouts tab click "Options".

Select "Adding currency signs to certain keys"

If the option is not here you may have to look into [setting up the keyboard 3rd level](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey).

Comment: Many thanks for the info - solved several problems for me.  Happy New Year to you.